# What is @ISA array in perl?

Tags: perl

```
our @ISA = "Critter";
```

In which condition will I use `@ISA`?

and why `our @ISA`?.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html

Comment: I don't think you want to assign `"Critter"` to `@ISA`, as the former is a scalar and the latter is an array.

Comment: I would not recommend directly assigning to `@ISA`. Use `use base 'Critter';` instead, or even newer `use parent 'Critter';`. They require the base module as well. See [base](http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html), [parent](http://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html) and [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To extend Mat's comment, stuff like this is extensively documented in the [`perldocs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/).

Regarding `@ISA`, [here's what it says](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#A-Class-is-Simply-a-Package):

> ### A Class is Simply a Package
>
> ...
>
> Each package contains a special array called `@ISA` . The `@ISA` array
>   contains a list of that class's parent classes, if any. This array is
>   examined when Perl does method resolution, which we will cover later.
>
> It is possible to manually set `@ISA` , and you may see this in older
>   Perl code. Much older code also uses the `base` pragma. For new code,
>   we recommend that you use the `parent` pragma to declare your parents.
>   This pragma will take care of setting `@ISA` . It will also load the
>   parent classes and make sure that the package doesn't inherit from
>   itself.
>
> However the parent classes are set, the package's `@ISA` variable will
>   contain a list of those parents. This is simply a list of scalars,
>   each of which is a string that corresponds to a package name.

`our` and `@ISA` go hand in hand because `@ISA` is expected to be a package variable.

Answer (score 8):

@ISA is stand for ‘is a’， that means the array contains parents' package

Comment: We rejected a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4091098) that should have been a separate answer or a comment instead. Just linking it if someone wants to see.